# How to save in chart original ID of element in array that is used to build chart data labels?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Let's say I have an array of users:

```
usersData = [
  { id: 21, name: 'John Dean' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Mike Brine' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Tom Kalvi' }
]
```

names in userData are generated from another array with full user information: **user.first_name + user.last_name**

When I build Vue-Chart Bar, **labels** array store this data with **indexes**:

```
labels = { 0: "John Dean", 1: "Mike Brine", 2: "Tom Kalvi" }
```

And when I want to get **original ID** from Bar event onClick, I receive only index.

I need to load additional information for each user based on Bar click, but I need to have original ID.

What is the easiest way to get it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have an index clicked just do like this:

`usersData[clickedIndex].id`

Comment: Thank you! What in case I have the following array?  {2: "Yasyrkin Alexey", 3: "Dietrich Sallie", 5: "Kovacek Elian", 6: "Schuster Orlando", 7: "Kihn Tristin", 8: "McKenzie Art", 9: "Rice Patricia", 10: "Nienow Coby", 11: "Keebler Loren", 12: "Bergexc Domenic", 13: "Goldner Walter", 14: "Zieme Chance", 15: "Sauer Deshaun", 16: "Purdy Jermey", 17: "Konopelski Dayana", 18: "Kunze Reginald", 20: "Howe Bar", 21: "Blinov Dmitry", 22: "Gankin Nikita"} meaning without ID

Comment: I'd suggest watching some JS tutorials.